# If it is called dynamically(v-bind:src), it does not print the image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, src, vue-cli

```
<template>
  //...
  <img v-bind:id="tileImages[0][1]" class='tileImages_big' v-bind:src="tileImages[0][0]" >
  //...
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() { return{
      tileImages:[],
      //...
</script>
```

(not working. image is not displayed)

When an image is loaded with string in "src", it is normally displayed on the screen, **but if it is called dynamically(v-bind:src), it does not print the image**.

The code below is the result of normal operation when I print the image with 'String src'.

```
<template>
  //...
  <img v-bind:id="tileImages[0][1]" class='tileImages_big' src="../upload/input_image/20200506044151_42517_10_small/000000.png" >
  //...
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() { return{
      tileImages:[],
      //...
</script>
```

(it works.)

[image]

The above image is the result of using 'v-bind:src'. There is no problem with the route, but the image is not recognized.

Below, I captured data and image structure just in case.

[image]
[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Try `require(tileImages[0][0])`

Comment: I applied this and this error occurred. . Error: Cannot find module '../upload/input_image/20200506044151_42517_10_small/000000.png'

Comment: Did you add it to the `src` like this: `v-bind:src="require(tileImages[0][0])"`?

Comment: Yes -> <img v-bind:id="tileImages[0][1]" class='tileImages_big' v-bind:src="require(tileImages[0][0])" >

Comment: Is there an error because I didn't use the webpack?